# how to bind data to notify js using javascript

Tags: javascript, notify

how to send dynamic data to notify js. how to get html span data in the var to append in java script notification

error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

html

```
<table align="center">
<tr><td><div class="start">Transformer Reading</div></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div class="box">DataFrame:-<span id="data"></span></div></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

javascript

```
<script>
        var value = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
        $.notify(value);
    </script>
```